CTRL-Y Redo not working on Jupyter Notebook
I have downloaded Anaconda on my work station, and CTRL-Y, which was the Redo shortcut, is no longer working. Instead, I could have to use CTRL-SHIFT-Z.
The following is my Jupyter version.
!jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.20.0
ipykernel        : 6.28.0
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 8.6.0
jupyter_core     : 5.5.0
jupyter_server   : 2.10.0
jupyterlab       : 4.0.11
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.10.0
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 7.0.8
qtconsole        : 5.4.2
traitlets        : 5.7.1

How can I make CTRL-Y work as Redo again?

Try Ctrl+ Shift+ Z

Have you read the question?

You can use the custom.js file to override the default key bindings.


Locate or create the custom.js file:


On Unix-based systems (Linux, macOS), the file is usually located at ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js.
On Windows, it is usually located at C:\Users\<YourUsername>\.jupyter\custom\custom.js.
If the custom folder or custom.js file does not exist, you will need to create them.


Edit the custom.js file to include the following script:

require(["base/js/namespace", "base/js/events"], function(Jupyter, events) {
    // Wait for the notebook to be fully loaded
    events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
        // Redefine the Ctrl-Y shortcut for Redo
        Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-y', {
            help : 'redo',
            help_index : 'zz',
            handler : function (event) {
                Jupyter.notebook.redo_cell();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});




Save the custom.js file and restart your Jupyter Notebook server.


These changes are for Jupyter Lab and not for Jupyter Notebook. My issues are with Jupyter Notebook.

Try above solution

You mean the chatGPT-created answer?

"These changes are for Jupyter Lab and not for Jupyter Notebook. My issues are with Jupyter Notebook." Starting with Jupyter Notebook 7, Jupyter Notebook shares the same underlying components with JupyterLab and so usually the solution written for JupyterLab are now the same solutions you want to be using with Jupyter Notebook 7+. Please read about the current Jupyter ecosystem in the bottom of my answer here. (I don't if that applies here to this specific issue but your broad dismissal rationalization is probably not appropriate these days.)

yes use the help of chatGPT @DarkBee
